# How to bulk update existing path alias after changing the URL alias pattern?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

How to bulk update existing URL alias?

I have [Path auto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module add path alias to URLs. I have changed the URL alias pattern. Now I want to update the pattern of old URLs also.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/254394/10592) answer is *really* worth reading first. It suggests a much more easy to control solution and gives a good explanation as to *why*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it works only to URL which does not have path alias – Vamsi

Then first go to `/admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk` and delete the aliases 
in question.

Then update `/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk`

Comment: it works only to URL which does not have path alias

Comment: @vamsi updated answer.

Comment: @Vamsi how did it go?

Answer (score 3):

go to configuration > Search and metadata > Url aliases > bulk generate.

If you already have already aliases and want to change them to the new ones you could delete all the content aliases first, is another option in url aliases.

Answer (score 2):

With Pathauto you can delete all the content aliases and then bulk generate new ones - but this **does not** address the problem if you have many pages with custom aliases mixed with automatic aliases as these will also be deleted.
Bulk generate will only generate aliases for nodes that are checked for automatic alias AND has *no alias* - deleted unchecked auto alias nodes will revert back to default pattern of node/#

To get around this issue you can use Administrative views (or your own view with bulk operations)

1. go to Pathauto and change your URL pattern to the new desired
   pattern.
2. go to admin/content (using Admin Views with VBO)
3. select all nodes with aliases you want to update
4. choose operation - unpublish
5. choose operation - publish
6. go see your new updated aliases :)

The idea here is just to change something so that the nodes are saved again, the aliases are updated with the current pattern upon save. and using VBO allows you to do as many as you want, and you could add extra exposed filters to your View to better select your list of nodes to update.