# Why are two url aliases being generated for some users?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, migrations, path-aliases

I have a site under development, that is a migration from an different cms via the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) module. I noticed that the links for a lot of my user profiles are not `staff/lastname-firstname` as I set in the pathauto settings, but `/firstname-lastname`.

Looking in the `url_alias` table I see one alias for `staff/lastname-firstname` (pid 1644030) and another one (pid 1644031) for `firstname-lastname`. I point out the pids just because it appears that they are probably being created one after the other. They are both marked as language undefined, most likely due to the neutral path module. I suspect that one of the aliases was originally meant to be for English and the second for Japanese, but there is no setting in pathauto for different language paths for users. I can try disabling the neutral path module and rerunning my migration to confirm that they were each meant for different languages, but how can I fix it? I do not need a `/firstname-lastname` path in the system. I only want `/staff/lastname-firstname` to be generated.

Comment: Back up db first, then delete them all, then use the Bulk Update tab in pathauto to re-create them.

Comment: I'm rerunning the migration a lot right now, and I believe they are getting recreated every time. I need to figure out how to keep them from being created in the first place.

Comment: true, but could be a migration thing, try [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200447/how-to-bulk-update-existing-path-alias-after-changing-the-url-alias-pattern/200448#200448) and see if they get re-created.

Comment: They do get recreated, now I get 2 that both point to the right place, which is less than ideal, but ok.  Unfortunately, the next time I run the migration it will be back to how it was.

Comment: I think I found the reason in my migration as you suggested,  somehow I missed it on the previous scan.

Comment: I had coded path into my users migration, and somehow overlooked it when I searched the migration for the code.  I've now updated that code to set the username to $row->username (a generated lastname-username) and the path to staff/username.  Pathauto is set to set user patterns to staff/[user:name], but somehow I'm getting the following generated: 
`1663643 user/53303 staff/bob-mcdonald und`
and
`1663644 user/53303 staff/mcdonald-bob und`

I'm confused about why username during the migration and the [user:name] token seem to be different.

Comment: I just removed pathauto for this migration, because for some reason it was getting the wrong token value, when I went into pathauto bulk generate to try to replicate the issue after migrating without pathauto it reported no new aliases to migrate, so it appears that the tokens get corrected after leaving the migration, so future paths should be correct.  Bulk deleting and recreating was the key debugging step, and making sure path and pathauto were properly configured in the migration was the key to actually fixing the issue.  Would you care to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then first go to `/admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk` and delete the aliases in question.

Disable Pathauto for the migration process.

Once your site has been migrated, then enable pathauto and do a bulk update `/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk`